# what satement is executed fast in oracle, Delete+insert OR insert where ID not in list.?

Tags: sql, optimization, oracle11g, sql-delete, procedure

I have a procedure with two tables ABC and EXT_ABC. EXT_ABC table is loaded with daily data ( EXT_ABC truncated at the end of every day) and ABC is loaded with everyday data from EXT_ABC to maintain history.Now sometime EXT_ABC bring updated data for ID already exist in ABC table, So we use follwoing logic.

```
DELETE FROM ABC WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM EXT_ABC);
commit;
INSERT INTO ABC
select * from EXT_ABC;
```

IS the above logic Fast or i can do the following to optimise the process as.

```
INSERT INTO ABC
select * from EXT_ABC where ID not in (SELECT ID FROM ABC );
```

Both tables have Index on ID column.

Comment: The second query should be faster, but I don't understand what you are trying to do in either case.

Comment: i am inserting data in ABC table from EXT_ABC. but it takes time, and i want to optimise the query, since i have to insert 6 Million + records everyday.

Comment: If EXT_ABC contains an ID already in ABC, is the rest of the data also identical to the data already in ABC?  If so then your second query would be faster.  If not, do you want the data in ABC updated? If not then your second query is still the way to go. If you want the matched records updated, then you either need to go with your first query, or use an update statement and then an insert statement, or use a MERGE statement with a when matched then update clause.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a Merge statement could be of use here, e.g.:

```
merge into abc tgt
  using ext_abc src
  on (tgt.id = src.id)
when not matched then
  insert (<list of target table columns>)
  values (<list of source table columns>);
```